# selectedvalue property in cascadingdropdown

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_group" CssClass="txtboxpr" Width="210px" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:CascadingDropDown ID="CascadingDropDown3" runat="server" Category="ProductGroup" SelectedValue='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Groupname")%>' TargetControlID="ddl_group" PromptText="[Select GroupName]" LoadingText="Loading GroupName..."
  ServicePath="~/Services_Product/Productname.asmx" ServiceMethod="GetDropDownProductName" Enabled="True">
</asp:CascadingDropDown>
```

I am setting my datasource using following query.

```
SELECT PName
      , Pid
      , ( 
          SELECT Gname 
          FROM   Pgroup INNER JOIN 
                 Product ON Pgroup.Groupname=Product.Groupname 
          WHERE (Product.id = @Ppname)
       ) as Groupname 
FROM Product
```

In the above code, the selected value property is not binding data . Can someone help me understand why?

Comment: What's your data source for the that. Please paste that code

Comment: Try this CascadingDropDown3.SelectedValue = "Value"

Comment: @Imad SELECT PName,Pid,(select Gname FROM Pgroup INNER JOIN Product ON Pgroup.Groupname=Product.Groupname  WHERE (Product.id = @Ppname))as Groupname FROM Product

Comment: @vivekkv It's showing an error 'The server tag is not well formed.'

Comment: C# code for binding??